# Cannot match regex expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've implemented the test regex below in Java but I can't see any matches. I'm new to regex but it looks like it should find a match. Anything I am doing wrong here?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String process= "SSHD is running: PID:12506, Wrapper:STARTED, Java:STOPPPED";
    Pattern patternFileToScan = Pattern.compile("SSHD is running: PID:[d]{1,5}, Wrapper:STARTED, Java:STARTED");
      Matcher matcherFileToScan = patternFileToScan.matcher(process);
      System.out.println("TEST");
      if(matcherFileToScan.matches()) {
          System.out.println(matcherFileToScan.group());
      }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `PID:[d]{1,5}` to `PID:\\d{1,5}`.

`[d]{1,5}` will try to match the character `d` not *numbers*.

Comment: @TheLostMind, you don't need to have char class.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Can't deny that  now .. can I? :P